# How to apply JoyPixels to Firefox browser?

Tags: firefox, fonts, emoji

How can I apply JoyPixels to Firefox browser? As you can see some emojis in Firefox are black and white, while others are colored. The link is [this](https://eosrei.github.io/emojione-color-font/full-demo.html).

[image: screenshot with emojis]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind editing the question to include some more information in your environment, i.e. linux distribution and/or firefox version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLOVED!]**

> As you can see some emojis in Firefox are black and white, while others are colored.

Some of black and white emojis are made by DejaVu font. After removing that font some of black and white emojis became colored.

> How can I apply JoyPixels to Firefox browser?

To apply JoyPixels to Firefox, you need to follow these instructions:

1. Install JoyPixels (`sudo pacman -S ttf-joypixels` for Arch Linux)
2. Run these commands:

   - `sudo ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/75-joypixels.conf  /etc/fonts/conf.d`
   - `fc-cache -f`

Answer (score 0):

This page appears to be using sans-serif font family. This should by the reason why it can't show all emoji properly.
Please try the following:

1. Open the [link](https://eosrei.github.io/emojione-color-font/full-demo.html).
2. Open Inspect element by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
3. On the right side you should see this

[image: filter styles]

4. Delete `, sans-serif`
5. Now you should be able to view all emojis normally.